# HighCharts: Visible não funciona

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estou tentando retirar o o xAxis com `visible: false` como mostrado na [documentação](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.visible), porem não está funcionando.

A versão do JQuery é: **v1.10.2 (2013-07-03)**. A versão do Highcharts é: **v4.0.3 (2014-07-03)**

Trecho do meu código JS do gráfico:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline'
            },
            credits:{
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Relatório'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Estatística de Desempenho'
            },

            xAxis:{
            visible: false
            },

            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit'
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Tendência',
                data: <?php echo $encodeValorTendencia; ?>
            }, {
                name: 'Obtenção',
                data: <?php echo $encodeValorObtencao; ?>
            }],

            legend: {
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            },

            tooltip: {
                shared: true
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 8000
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa propriedade só é válida a partir da versão 4.1.9, conforme informações do próprio Highcharts  - mencionada acima

Funciona com a última versão: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscariello2/1t0k2nf5/1/
, mas não com a 4.0.3 http://jsfiddle.net/carloscariello2/1t0k2nf5/3/

Comment: Isso resolveu, mas somente quando chamo pelo https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, mas se baixo o conteúdo desse endereço, e chamo um arquivo do diretório, o gráfico funciona, porem, a função visible não funciona. Você tem ideia do que possa ser?